# Using だった for things that haven't changed

Tags: tense

I'm a little confused by the tenses in the following monologue taken from the beginning of a manga chapter:

```
 黒い服が好きだった
 昏い闇の中に居ても
 安心して溶け込んでいられるから 　　
 この年になっても私は 　　
 中二病を拗らせたままでいる
```

Now, in my native language a phrase like "I liked dark clothes" would normally imply that this is not the case anymore. However, here the character proceeds to explain that her preferences haven't changed (in fact, on the last frame she is shown wearing a black top). Is there no such implication in japanese? Or does the first line beg for an additional いつも?

Comment: I believe the same implication exists in Japanese as well, which is why there was a need for the author to explain that it is still the case

Comment: I’m curious. What tense does your language use when you want to describe a past state without suggesting whether or not that state is still continuing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence

> 黒い服が好きだった

can be interpreted as a shortened form of

> 黒い服が昔から好きだった

which implies that the character's preferences haven't changed.